# Thermoregulatory characteristics

Tags: evolution, thermoregulation

I have a question that probably is to obvious, or just bad wording..

The terms endorthermy, ectothermy, and heterothermy, are used to describe:
A) cold and warm individuals
B) the three layers of the skin
C) different types of body cavities
D) the source of an animals heat
E) none of the above

I think it's E) or D). My thinking process is B and C completely irrelevant.  A) i think it is very ambiguous as an answer as those three terms refer to a type of classification rather than the characteristic itself (like if their skin is cold or warm). On the other hand D) the source of an animals heat, doesn't seem very right to me. The 3 terms refer to the source of the heat that predominatly determines the body temperature, meaning that it is not THE SOURCE, but the way they exchange and regulate their temperature... That means that probably it is E?!

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/61444/are-homeothermic-and-endothermic-synonymous

Comment: "The 3 terms refer to the source of the heat that predominatly determines the body temperature, meaning that it is not THE SOURCE, but the way they exchange and regulate their temperature". What do you mean by this? We use heat to change our core body temperature so why does this seem wrong?

Comment: @ANNAMARIA I am not sure I understand what kind of semantic issue you are pointing to for answer D. But, in short, I don't think it is such a trick question. The answer is D.